# listview onTap animating all the buttons issue :Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-animatedlist

GestureDetector on listview animating all the widgets in the listview, how do i stop this.
I have Transform.scale on a listview item , when i tap on the widget only that widget should animate 
but here all the other listview items are animating.

```
Widget buildItemCoupens(BuildContext context,int index) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
  child: Container(
    height: 250,
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[

        Positioned(
          bottom: -25,
          right: 50,
          left: 50,
          top: 175,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTapDown: _onTapDown,
            onTapCancel: onTapCancel,
            onTapUp: _onTapUp,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                print('$index');
              });
            },
            child:_animatedBtn
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

animated button/widget

```
Widget get _animatedBtn=>
Transform.scale(
  scale: _scale,
  child: Container(
    //height: 75,

    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 15, right: 15, top: 5, bottom: 45),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: const Radius.circular(15.0),
            bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(15.0),
            bottomRight: const Radius.circular(15.0),
            topRight: const Radius.circular(15.0)),
        boxShadow: [
          new BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black38,
            blurRadius: 15,
          ),
        ]),
    child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Text(
            'JOIN NOW',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        )),
  ),
);
```

Comment: please add code

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pskink/e1026422c2a2c37df60e2b750656a0dc

Comment: @pskink working , but is this an issue ? can i know more

Comment: what is an issue?

Comment: @pskink animating all the other listview items by taping only one widget in the listview .Did you get it?

Comment: your program is doing exactly what you wrote, how can i say anything if i didnt see it?